# Which profiles to choose for Code Signing Identity versus signing for distribution versus Code Signing Entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode

I have read the Apple documentation, and many postings on the subject on SO, along with various tutorials, and yet I have to admit I don't 100% understand what profiles to use when and how, and usually resort to trial and error until I find a combination that works.

However at the moment I'm in the situation that an ad-hoc app (that used to install) via iTunes now no longer does either on my phone or on tester's phones, though it will install using XCode. The error message on the phone is juts "ZZZ failed to install.".

I have the following profiles installed in XCode:
1) Ad-hoc distribution profile
2) Team provisioning profile
3) Development profile
4) Apple Push Profile

Some questions:

1) Which profile should I use in the Code Signing Identity section of the Target Build Settings and why?

2) Which profile should I use when distributing an Ad-Hoc Deployment?

I would assume for 2) it should be the Ad-hoc distribution profile? If not what/when should that profile be used?

If the Ad-Hoc distribution profile is used in step 2) then I guess I have to use the Apple Push Profile in step 1)? Otherwise how can I receive APNs?

When then should I be using the other profiles?

A few follow up questions:
3) In what circumstances would or should you set a different code signing identity in the Project to the Target?

4) By default there are 5 sections in the Code Signing Identity (Code Signing Identity, Debug, Debug Any iOS SDK, Release, Release Any iOS SDK). In general should these all be the same? Under what circumstances would or should they be different?

5) What is the Code Signing Entitlements section used for?

I've been working with iOS development for quite a while, and would consider myself advanced in many areas, but this one just does my head in.

Many thanks if somebody can demystify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Development profile, must be generated **after** APNS profile. You don't sign bundles with APNS certificate, it is for server. But in you development and ad-hoc profile will be part with info about Push Notifications, so you need to re-creare dev and ad-hoc profiles after changes in APNS settings in provisioning portal. For proper usage of APNS you should read additional materials, like [that](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/) or any other. If app has no APNS, you can use team provisioning profile with your developer name for debugging as well.

**2)** Yep, Ad-hoc.

**3)** If you have more then one target in the project

**4)** I used development profile as "Debug" (same in "Debug Any iOS SDK") and ad-Hoc profile as "Release" (same in "Release Any iOS SDK)".

Welcome to crazy world of app signing!

Comment: Thanks, however I tried changing the code signing identity to the development profile but I still get the error. I've been using this combination of profiles sucessfully for several weeks so they must be capable of working. But I've no idea what's changed in the last few days to stop things from working. Maybe I'll just re-create everything, that seems to be the stock solution when all else fails.

Comment: Is current ad-hoc profile installed on testing devices? And how do you send ad-hoc bundles to devices - with itunes or via web? Maybe error is not in Xcode signing (maybe it is there). Also, as widely used solution I can suggest deleting all certificates from Xcode and installing them again. Sometimes this trick can help.

Comment: I got things to work - I noticed I had a lot of keys in the keystore, some must be old from older versions of profiles. I cleared out a lot of stuff and it started working. Why it would work last week and not this when I didn't change anything is a mystery.